# Windows 10 Bluetooth Speakers Disconnecting after 10 seconds

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, speakers

I am using an Acer Swift 3 laptop and Samsung AKG Bluetooth speakers. The speakers connect without any issues and stay connected until I try and play any music/video (spotify/youtube etc) - when I do so they disconnect after about 10/20 seconds.

I have tried uninstalling the Bluetooth driver, but this hasn't worked. I know that the issue is not with the speakers as they used to work fine with a Dell laptop I had previously.

Any hlep will be much appreciated!

Comment: Will resetting the bluetooth module helps? Shift-Option click the BT menu bar item > Debug > Reset the Bluetooth module.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so here's an answer instead - I think this has to do with the power plan you've chosen. My HP notebook does this with my mouse when it goes into battery saving mode.